# grep for lines in log file which do not contain a certain word

Tags: regex, logging, grep

I am trying to analyze a log file. I am looking for maybe a regular expression, which fulfills the following requirement:

```
LOG: https://localhost/a
LOG: https://remotehost/x
LOG: https://localhost/b
LOG: https://localhost/c
LOG: https://remotehost/a
```

Above is an example of a log file. **Question:** How can I grep through the log file, such that I get only the lines not containing:

```
https://localhost
```

The result should be:

```
LOG: https://remotehost/x
LOG: https://remotehost/a
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `grep -v <word> <filename>`

From `grep` manual (FreeBSD):

```
-v, --invert-match
    Invert the sense of matching, to select non-matching lines.
```

Comment: Oh, wow. Thank you. Next time I'll read the manpages more carefully.